# T-SQL SUM() for each row without last 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a table in SQL that looks something like this:

```
NAME    stage 1    stage 2    stage 3    stage 4    stage 5

PersonA   3         1           4          6           7
PersonB   1         1           6          2           9
PersonC   0         0           1          0          10
```

For each row I need to calculate the SUM excluding the last 2 columns (i.e. sum of stage 1 through stage 3) and have it appear as a separate column. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are stage1 - stage5 base table columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4, Stage5, 
    Stage1 + Stage2 + Stage3 AS SumOfFirst3Stages
FROM dbo.TableName
```

You may have been thinking you needed to use the SUM operator, but all you need to do is add the 3 together as above, and give it an alias to return that extra column as.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Stage1 + Stage2 + Stage3 AS Stage1_3
FROM Table
```